# Messy Date Formatting

Tags: python, datetime

There can only be better ways to do this?

- create strings for  today's directory
- `strDate` is yesterday's date in format ddmmyyyy (e.g. 08122016)
- `DateStr` is yesterday's date in format yymmdd (e.g 161208)

```
strDate = '{d.year}{d.month:02}{d.day:02}'.format(d=datetime.datetime.now()- timedelta(1))
strDate = str(strDate)

day = calendar.day_name[datetime.datetime.today().weekday()-1]
day = day[:3]

week  = datetime.datetime.today().isocalendar()[1]

fpath = strDate + "_" + str(day)  + "_" +  str(week) + ".zip"

DateStr = '{d.day:02}{d.month:02}{d.year}'.format(d=datetime.datetime.now()- timedelta(1))
DateStr = str(DateStr[:4]+DateStr[6:])
```

Comment: Can you add a description as to what this code is doing. Also some example output would be nice.

Comment: Is this code part of a program? Why are you using three different date formats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Formatting dates

Simpler way to produce your required the formats is using the [strftime symbols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), for example:

```
# yesterday's date in format ddmmyyyy (e.g. 08122016)
strDate = '{:%d%m%Y}'.format(d - timedelta(1))

# yesterday's date in format yymmdd (e.g 161208)
DateStr = '{:%y%m%d}'.format(d - timedelta(1))
```

#### Formattings dates to use in filenames

I would strongly discourage using any of these formats in filenames.
Consider adopting the yyyymmdd format instead.
The good thing about this format is that the alphabetic ordering is the same as chronological ordering,
which is often very practical.

#### String conversions

The `format` function of a string returns a string.
So the second line here is unnecessary:

> ```
> strDate = '{d.year}{d.month:02}{d.day:02}'.format(d=datetime.datetime.now()- timedelta(1))
> strDate = str(strDate)
> ```

#### String concatenation

String concatenation like this is not recommended:

> ```
> fpath = strDate + "_" + str(day)  + "_" +  str(week) + ".zip"
> ```

Better use the format function:

```
fpath = '{}_{}_{}.zip'.format(strDate, day, week)
```

#### Other Python conventions

The `strDate` and `DateStr` variable names go against the recommended naming convention.
I suggest to read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it explains this and other recommendations to follow.